# Why are butterflies drinking blood?

Tags: zoology

According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq2H8tNyk4Q) video, butterflies sometimes drink blood. Do they have the organs necessary to digest blood? I thought they eat only salts and nectar, which are easy to digest compared to proteins.

**@aandreev**

**100mg/dL** is the human blood sugar content (I assume it is similar in other animals). Afaik. sugar energy density is about **4kcal/g**. A butterfly is about **1g** of weight, which means **1mL** if we count with water. So it can drink around **0.5mL** of blood. That means **0.5mL×100mg/dL×4kcal/g = 0.002kcal = 8.4J**. The top butterfly speed is about **12 mph**, so I think we can count with **6mph** by an average butterfly, which is about **2.7m/s**. So it needs **1/2×1g×(2.7m/s)<sup>2</sup> = 0.0036J** kinetic energy to move and **1g×9.81m/s<sup>2</sup>×1m = 0.0098J** potential energy to keep the 1m height of flight. I think we can guess that it loses this kind of energy in **2secs**, which means it needs **0.0134J/2s = 0.0067W** power to fly. So the **0.5mL** blood means **8.4J/0.0067W = 24925s = 21min** of flight time, which is not much compared to nectar (**30g/dL$, $2500J$, $100h**). Ofc. this is just a very rough estimation (the real flight time is probably much lower) based on data coming from non-scientific sources, but I think you can see the difference.

Comment: For salt content I think. Not sure enough to answer but blood is full of nice things besides calories.

Comment: calories in blood are glucose

Comment: @aandreev I edited the question.

Comment: what about salts though?

Comment: @aandreev Find evidence and send an answer. This is how science works. :-) http://scholar.google.com

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematophagy

Comment: I am quite sure blood contains far far more than just glucose. Most of the compounds in blood (proteins, lipids) can all be oxidised.

Comment: @MarchHo Ofc. they can be used to produce energy, but can a butterfly digest proteins and fats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't watch the video so I don't know if this was mentioned. Butterflies will exhibit a behavior called [mud puddling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud-puddling) which occurs mainly with male butterflies [[1]](http://www.stanford.edu/group/CCB/Pubs/Boggs_pdfs/1991%20Boggs%20&%20Jackson%20puddling.pdf). Puddling is when butterflies seek out moist surfaces in order to consume the fluid. Butterflies will puddle in soil, dung, carrion (rotting flesh/meat), etc. Boggs and Jackson claim that puddling falls into two categories which aren't mutually exclusive [[1]](http://www.stanford.edu/group/CCB/Pubs/Boggs_pdfs/1991%20Boggs%20&%20Jackson%20puddling.pdf):

1. scarce nutrients for example sodium
2. competitive exclusion of males or young individuals from flowers

But we can see blood isn't the only option for puddling. Basically anything that provides moisture and nutrients will do.

Comment: This competition for flowers is very new to me, I did not know that butterflies can fight each other. :-)

Comment: @in3rno I choose you Butterfree! Use Sleep Powder on the other Butterfree! Seriously though, I would assume they use the same tactics as birds...minus the beak stabbing, and vocalizations?